# Smarty and gettext

Tags: php, smarty, gettext

What's the easiest way to use gettext combined with smarty, is there some simalar function as there is available in php: `_('hello world');` ?

Thanks,

Comment: Just a thought: normally, you can use any php function as a modifier in smarty.  Wouldn't something like `{$var|gettext}` work?  By the time smarty code is executing all locale settings should have taken place.

Answer (score 4):

I really found the support of Smarty for (n)gettext quite lacking as well. And while the existing plugin(s) seem to do a fair job, I still thought I should give it a go.

I've just released: http://code.google.com/p/smarty-gettext/

Maybe it's of help to anyone. Feedback, etc. more than appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's a `smarty-gettext` plugin available: http://sourceforge.net/projects/smarty-gettext/, last updated May 2011.  http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyGettext

Comment: @MauritsMeester "Easy" wasn't a criterion specified in your question :)

Comment: I think this plugin is as easy as it gets. There are alternatives that are easier (without gettext). For instance, you could write your own template function and use it like this: `{lang en="coffee" de="Kaffee"}`. However, this way all strings are in the files - YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of ways to achieve a translation of a page with Smarty.

## My way

I create some `.conf` files containing something like:

### en.conf

```
hello_world = "Hello! World!"
my_name_is = "They call me"
```

### nl.conf

```
hello_world = "Hallo! Wereld!"
my_name_is = "Ik heet"
```

### fr.conf

```
hello_world = "Bonjour! Tout le Monde!"
my_name_is = "Ils m'appellent"
```

Now you have 2 options:

- You can load the `.conf` file from the `.tpl` file:
- Or you want PHP to handle the right file. (I use this method)

### template.tpl (English)

```
{config_load file="en.conf"}

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{#hello_world#}</h1>
        <p>
            {#my_name_is#}
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### template.tpl (Dutch)

```
{config_load file="nl.conf"}

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{#hello_world#}</h1>
        <p>
            {#my_name_is#}
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### template.php (Using Smarty Class in PHP)

```
 $configFile = 'fr.conf';

 // Smarty Version 2
 $this->smarty->config_load($configFile);

 //Smarty Version 3
 $this->smarty->configLoad($configFile);
```

I hope this works out for you as well.

Comment: the OP is inquiring specifically about `gettext` not how to do i18n in smarty.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong. I use Smarty 3.1, added to my project via composer. And it seems to be the case that I am able to execute any php function in my .tpl file. For example:

```
<p>post_max_size: {ini_get('post_max_size')}</p>
```

it gives me:

```
<p>post_max_size: 8M</p>
```

That behaviour makes me think that I should be able to do simply:

```
<p>{_("I like the way it works")}</p>
```

The first test shows no error and outputs:

```
<p>I like the way it works</p>
```

I have no translation file yet and i don't know if the call will be recognized by xgettext but i will do some tests now and will tell you if it works.